# Instantiating Appium IOS/Android driver

Tags: appium, appium-ios, appium-android

I'm using appium-dotnet-driver v4.0.0.4 beta of the appium nuget package (but I have downgraded to the previous versions too and I'm getting the same issue)

So I've never used it before, therefore not entirely sure how it should work. Currently I'm doing this:

```
private static AppiumDriver<AppiumWebElement> mobileDriver;

       AppiumOptions opt = new AppiumOptions();
        opt.AddAdditionalCapability("autoWebview", true);

        switch (platform.ToLower())
        {
            case "ios":
                {
                    foreach (var cap in MobileSettingsFileConstants.iosCapabilities)
                    {
                        opt.AddAdditionalCapability(cap.Key, cap.Value);
                    }
                    mobileDriver = new IOSDriver<AppiumWebElement>(GridUri, opt);
                    break;
                }
```

When ever it tries to add an additional capability  to `Appium Options` I get an exception : `Exception thrown: 'System.MissingMethodException' in appium-dotnet-driver.dll`, `Additional information: Method not found: 'Void OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DesiredCapabilities.set_Item`

I've had a look on the appium forum and they said this was an issue. Can someone share their experience with this please?

Comment: You must define all the required DesiredCapabilities in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out I had to be at the latest version on Selenium on **both** test framework and test solution.

Simple answer to a mind boggling question.